# chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired Listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

i'm trying to intercept the proxy authorization inside a chrome extension.
Following the answer to here: [Domain Authorization in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778559/domain-authorization-in-chrome-extension) and reading the docs [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onAuthRequired) my code looks like this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function(details, callbackFn) {
        console.log("onAuthRequired!", details, callbackFn);
        //callback({
        //    authCredentials: {username: "1", password: "__TestUse"}
        //});
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

The problem is that callbackFn is **undefined** but should be a function.

Anyone got some ideas why callbackFn is undefined. As I read the docs I'm doing it right ..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code works, I just forgot to add another parameter `['asyncBlocking']`.
This code works just fine:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    function(details, callbackFn) {
        console.log("onAuthRequired!", details, callbackFn);
        callbackFn({
            authCredentials: {username: "1", password: "__TestUser"}
        });
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ['asyncBlocking']
);
```

Note that you need the `webRequest` and `webRequestAuthProvider`  permissions for Manifest V3 (available as of Chrome 108): https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onAuthRequired

Comment: how does this work anyway in manifest v3? asynBlocking and blocking throws error, as blocking should be now in declarativeNetRequest.

Comment: stay with v2 for now https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1135492

Comment: Note that as of v108 Chrome supports a new permission `webRequestAuthProvider`: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onAuthRequired