# Chrome Extension Config Proxy UserName and Password

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am creating a chrome extension for changing proxy settings dynamically. But in "chrome.proxy.settings.set" function its not possible to config userName and password for the proxy. So every time I have to manually enter credentials once settings are changed.

But I found that in [Proxy Auto Auth](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-auto-auth/ggmdpepbjljkkkdaklfihhngmmgmpggp) extension its some how configuring username and password programmatically.  I could not find any documentation on how to do this.

I would be grateful if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing it by using the [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to intercept and answer the auth request.

See [`onAuthRequired` event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onAuthRequired). You'll need host, `"webRequest"` and `"webRequestBlocking"` permissions.

Comment: Hi Xan Thanks for the help. I could resolve the issue using ur solution. Found sample code in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612968/chrome-webrequest-onauthrequired-listener

Thanks !