# How to handle authentication popup in Chrome with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to handle an authentication pop-up in one of my new Webdriver scripts.  I have a working solution for IE, but I am struggling with Chrome.  IE was as simple as following the advice on [this page]:[How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java?answertab=active#tab-top). That thread doesn't show a great solution for Chrome, although several commentors point out, that the solution does not work for Chrome.  The problem is, when you try to do the below code on Chrome, the login popup isn't an Alert.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
 Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
 alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(**username**, **password**));
```

It's not a windows level () authentication pop-up, the web page is simply password protected. I know there are several other instances of this question on Stack Overflow, but I don't see any more recently than 2 years old.  I am hoping there is a better solution now in 2017.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the website?

Comment: I would love to, but we have had several security issues in the last 2 years here, and I know my manager would be nervous about my sharing the link.  It is a public facing dev site, which is why they have password protected it.

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://seleniumwebdrivertrainings.com/how-to-perform-basic-authentication-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-iedriver-in-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: That site suggests the same as others, namely: create an instance of FFdriver with a custom profile, and then use the http://user:pass@domain.com trick.  When I try it, it doesn't work.  Interestingly, if I try that URL manually in a regular FF browser I get the following message:

You are about to log in to the site “domain.net” with the username “autotest”, but the website does not require authentication. This may be an attempt to trick you.

Is “domain.net” the site you want to visit?

Comment: check this answer, with selenium 4 it's easy https://stackoverflow.com/a/67321556/7604647

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*edit **Chrome no longer supports this.**

Isn't that a "restricted" pop-up that can be handled by prepending the address with username and password?

Instead of `driver.get("http://www.example.com/");` go for `driver.get("http://username:password@www.example.com");`.

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work for me.  It may be an issue with the way our website is prompting for credentials, or maybe I have not properly setup Chrome to handle http://user:pass@www.address.com?

Comment: So this was the answer.  I was trying to do "http ://username:password@www.domain.com".  I needed to be doing "httpS://username:password@domain.com".

Comment: @TravisNeedham I am also trying but it doesn't work for me. My password contain @ already. So how can I handle in this case ? Pls suggest

Comment: Chrome no longer supports this. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5669008342777856  Answer is out of date.

Comment: @Vaibhav_Sharma I would change my password and remove the @ in it.  I don't think there is a way to escape it.

Comment: @Vaibhav_Sharma This still works in chrome. But we need to carefully observe how web app is getting authenticated. For e.g., app url may be https://app.url however after hitting the url, it redirects to https://auth.server.url. So if you append username and password into app.url it wont work. It should be appended to auth.server.url. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 19):

May be helpful for others to solve this problem in chrome with the help of chrome extension. Thanks to @SubjectiveReality who gave me this idea.

Sending username and password as part of url like https://username:password@www.mytestsite.com may be helpful if same server performs both authentication and hosts the application. However most corporate applications have firmwide authentications and app server may reroute the request to authentication servers. In such cases, passing credentials in URL wont work.

Here is the solution:

#Step1: Create chrome extension#

1. Create a folder named 'extension'
2. Create a file named 'manifest.json' inside 'extension' folder. Copy below code into the file and save it.

> {
> "name":"Webrequest API",
> "version":"1.0",
> "description":"Extension to handle Authentication window",
> "permissions":["<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"],
> "background": {
> "scripts" : ["webrequest.js"]
> },
> "manifest_version": 2
> }

3. Create a file named 'webrequest.js' inside 'extension' folder and copy paste below code into the file and save it.

> ```
> chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
> function handler(details){
>  return {'authCredentials': {username: "yourusername", password: "yourpassword"}};
> },
> {urls:["<all_urls>"]},
> ['blocking']);
> ```

4. Open chrome browser, go to chrome://extensions and turn on developer mode
5. Click 'Pack Extension', select root directory as 'extension' and pack extension. It should create a file with extension '.crx'

#Step2: Add extension into your test automation framework #

1. Copy the .crx file into your framework
2. Configure your webdriver creation to load the extension like

> ```
> options.addExtensions(new File("path/to/extension.crx"));
> options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
> ```

3. Invoke your webdriver and application URL
4. You wont see the authentication popup appearing as its handled by above extension

Happy Testing!

**References:**

http://www.adambarth.com/experimental/crx/docs/webRequest.html#apiReference
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onAuthRequired
[chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612968/chrome-webrequest-onauthrequired-listener)
https://gist.github.com/florentbr/25246cd9337cebc07e2bbb0b9bf0de46

Comment: Nice! Another way to accomplish is to add the extension unpacked as an argument, like `options.AddArgument(@"--load-extension=" + Path.GetTempPath() + "\\extensionSource");`, where you save your .js and manifest to the path of your choosing

Comment: Work with few updates, need to check the following urls

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612968/chrome-webrequest-onauthrequired-listener

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757424/runtime-error-on-chrome-extension
since few thing has been changed and the current code does not work

Comment: I have problems getting this working. addListener has now been deprecated so unsure what to use and when I go to generate a Pack Extension I get a Failed to output private key at root directory, despite this being listed as optional?

Comment: I have my code in my local machine and I am running my testcase in virtual machine  to which I don't have any access. I have tried robot ( co-ordinate) method which is not working again. By following above provided solution where the .crx file will get generated. What should I do to handle the above situation? @Bhuvanesh Mali

Comment: You will create the .crx file in your local machine. Couple this .crx plugin with your remote driver instance which will be sent to your remote machine and plugin will get eventually loaded. Even i am running my script on remote selenium grid and this works fine.

Answer (score 7):

Updated answer of the solution provided by @Bhuvanesh Mani

*manifest.json*

```
    {
        "name": "Webrequest API",
        "version": "1.0",
        "description": "Extension to handle Authentication window",
        "permissions": [
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking",
            "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "background": {
            "scripts": [
                "webrequest.js"
            ]
        },
        "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

*webrequest.js*

```
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details){
        console.log("chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired event has fired");
        return {
                authCredentials: {username: "yourusername", password: "yourpassword"}
            };
    },
    {urls:["<all_urls>"]},
    ['blocking']);
```

Not certain why the '--no sandbox' option is required, but for me this is not required.

I did need to perform a registry edit to allow adding extensions since this is disabled with a corporate AD policy:

- Open regedit.exe as admin
- navigate to
  Computer\HKEY_USERS\

  Change the REG_SZ value that is now set to `*` to for example `-`.

  restart the chrome instance in which you want add extensions to.

The only difference with the original answer is the url's that also need to be present in the permissions.

*extra's*
if you want to see console output, turn on developer mode and click on the `Inspect views background page` for your extension in the extensions screen in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I know your situation is Java, but this might be helpful. I was able to get past the alert using this approach in C#:

```
// I am using a static instance of the driver for this.
Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
var alert = Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SendKeys($"{Driver.user_name}" + Keys.Tab + $"{Driver.user_password}" + Keys.Tab);
alert.Accept();
Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

I then utilized a test user account as the values of the user_name and password.

Comment: I get a timeout on GoToUrl(url), even though the alert is displayed.  Chrome v74 with  chromedriver v74.

Comment: This isnt working for me because as @SubjectiveReality said, its stuck in invoking URL itself which displaying the user authentication popup... sad, couldnt find the solution for this problem yet!

Comment: @BhuvaneshMani you can launch chrome with an unpacked extension with `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener`, though that doesn't work in headless mode.

Comment: @SubjectiveReality That seems to be attractive solution, do you have java code handy that i can use this listener approach? Meanwhile i will try it out.

Comment: Never mind, i have solved this problem by creating extension.

Comment: @SubjectiveReality I have created extension and successfully loading while creating the session in remote node. But after browser loads with extension, its just not responding to selenium webdriver anymore. Even the first line, driver.get(URL) fails with message as Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60.0. It responds if i load browsers without extensions. So looks like i need to do something with extension? Like creating a background page for extension?

Comment: @BhuvaneshMani you may need to add the `--no-sandbox` argument to your options, and possibly before the extension.  Also, last I looked, loading unpacked extensions is not supported in conjunction with `--headless`, in case that is tripping you up.

Comment: @SubjectiveReality Thanks, I have no sandbox, loading extension before that and my tests are NOT headless. After long hours, i found that its NOT working only for chrome version 73.0 and working perfectly in all other chrome versions. Looks like version specific chrome bug.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException: 'no such alert (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)'

Answer (score 1):

**Selenium 4** supports authenticating using Basic and Digest auth . It's using the CDP and currently only supports chromium-derived browsers

**Java Example :**

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

((HasAuthentication) driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of("username", "pass"));

driver.get("http://sitewithauth");
```

**Note :** In Alpha-7 there is **bug** where it send username for both user/password. Need to wait for next release of selenium version as fix is available in trunk https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/4917444886ba16a033a81a2a9676c9267c472894

Comment: This works fine with my local setup but HasAuthentication doesn't supported by remoteWebDriver yet.