# Upgrading Manifest V2 to V3, will <all_urls> in web accessible resources trigger a disable and warning on upgrade?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

We have a decent number of users for our Chrome extension. Some number of users are lost whenever permissions change and the extension gets disabled until the user approves the permissions, so we only do it as a last resort.

Upgrading to manifest V3 has changes I'm concerned about regarding disabling and warning on upgrade.

1. `host_permissions` -- if we're NOT changing host permissions, just upgrading the manifest to comport with V3 standards, will this disable and warn the user on upgrade?
2. `web_accessible_resources` -- the extension works on too many sites to maintain a list of matches, so I opted for `<all_urls>`, as below, will it trigger a disable and warning?

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["*.png", "*.svg"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
```

3. The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) say matches for content scripts are treated like permissions for the purposes of the web store review--does that mean this could trigger a disable on upgrade to V3, even if they don't change?

Comment: 1. no, 2. no, 3. no because it's the same as in mv2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66867507/1407491

Comment: "all_urls" doesn't seem to valid anymore, which is dumb