# How to By Pass NTLM authentication pop up while performing automation testing using Selenium web driver for Chrome browser?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I used the following python code to bypass the NTLM popup.

```py
chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options)
chromedriver.get("https://username:password@url.com")
```

The popup couldn't bypass and still exists and test breaks.

Comment: I am getting 503 Service temporarily unavailable error.

Comment: @coder123 do you know the URL/Port the authentication redirects to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be facing issue for domain login as browser converts domain separator `\` to `/` and credentials become invalid. Use encoded separator `%5C` and it will work.

Browser will convert `https://domain\username:password@URL` to `https://domain/username:password@URL`.

User encoded separator for request.
`https://domain\username:password@URL` => `https://domain%5Cusername:password@URL`

Comment: Thanks man, that encoding stuff saved me... after 5 days :) tried everything but this.

Answer (score 3):

As [@BhuvaneshMani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5885718/bhuvanesh-mani) has mentioned in the comment's on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115020/8179099)...

You need to observe how the NTLM is getting authenticated. (use the devTools in chrome under Network)

After you find the authentication call use that URL!

As [@BhuvaneshMani's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5885718/bhuvanesh-mani) example:

> `For e.g., app url may be app.url however after hitting the url, it redirects to auth.server.url. So if you append username and password into app.url it wont work. It should be appended to auth.server.url.`

So your code should look something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://username:password@auth.server.com")
```

Or (I found that most authentication calls are to the same URL just to the server port: `port:8080/auth/login`)

```
driver.get("https://username:password@url.com:8080/auth/login")
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also enable Chrome to authenticate with NTLM as the **current user** with similar `.reg` file to the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*.companydomain.org,*.companydomain.coop"
"AuthSchemes"="basic,digest,ntlm,negotiate"
"AuthServerWhitelist"="*.companydomain.org,*.companydomain.coop"
```

https://dev.to/seankilleen/quick-tip-ntlm-windows-pass-through-authentication-with-selenium-and-chromedriver-34m6