# How to handle "Authentication required" window in Selenium?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to enter Username and Password in Authentication required window in Chrome, but it's not working due to

> NoAlertPresentException

[image]

So my software just waiting for alert to pop-up, then getting this exception and trying again in 3 seconds and it's just looping like there is no any alert at all.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SetAuthenticationCredentials(User,Pass);
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

I found similar question and the only answer was to use this method, but it's not working for me too because of DNS error, seems like I can't authenticate using this.

```
 driver.get("http://Username:Password@SiteURL")
```

Comment: Yeah, this is not a traditional alert and `username:password@url` is the most common and straightforward way to bypass it.

Comment: Do you know what is it then? I can't right click it or find in console to locate it using driver.FindElement, so I don't actually understand what can I do here.

Comment: I'd focus on the DNS error and try to figure out why cannot you pass username/password via url. You could explore extension route as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56285073/771848

Comment: Extension doesn't work, it just can't see this alert x(

Comment: You cannot get that with pure browser tech (selenium), but if you're running on Windows, you can get to it using Windows UI automation

Answer (score 0):

You can add nuget package AutoIT and login to a windows auth box.