# How to handle server authentication popup in Chrome browser with Selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I followed the solution given by @obiwankoban and @SubjectiveReality mentioned at the following link: 
[How to handle authentication popup in Chrome with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114940/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-in-chrome-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

I performed the below steps:

1. Created a folder called 'Extension'
2. Created following two files inside Extension folder.
   manifest.json

   {
   "name": "Webrequest API",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "Extension to handle Authentication window",
   "permissions": [
   "webRequest",
   "webRequestBlocking",
   ""
   ],
   "background": {
   "scripts": [
   "webrequest.js"
   ]
   },
   "manifest_version": 2
   }

webrequest.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details){
console.log("chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired event has fired");
return {
authCredentials: {username: "getestone", password: "Viacom@2020"}
};
},
{urls:["<all_urls>"]},
['blocking']);
```

3. Updated Pack extension on chrome browser, post which .crx file gets created.
4. My Selenium code is as follows:

Selenium code

```
    public class openWebsite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    File addonpath = new 
    File("C:\\Users\\10642575\\Desktop\\Work\\Automation\\AuthPopUp\\Extension.crx");

    ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
    chrome.addExtensions(addonpath);
    //options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    "C:\\Users\\10642575\\Desktop\\Work\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
    driver.get("https://uat.contentplatform.viacom.com/");


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("getest.one@viacom.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();

    }
    }
```

On following the above steps, I still get the server authentication pop up when the website is launched on chrome. Authentication bypass is not working.

**PLZ HELP**

Comment: it worked. made a small change in the selenium code 
    options.addExtensions(addonpath);

Comment: how do we create the extension files(manifest.json and javascript file) for other browsers like chrome, IE and safari? Code will be helpful @bhuvaneshm87