# Python selenium headless start with extensions and xfvb

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to run a headless Chrome process with an extension<sup>1</sup>. I'm using WSL.

For testing purposes I can use one of two browsers:

- Ubuntu: `Google Chrome 86.0.4240.183`
- Windows: `Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

For production purposes the Ubuntu's Chrome is the only viable option<sup>2</sup>.

The rest of the stack:

- Python 3.6.9
- selenium: 3.141.0

In order to overcome Chrome not being able to start headlessly with extensions I use `PyVirtualDisplay`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600), backend='xvfb')
display.start()

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('/home/plonca/selenium_draft/extensions.crx')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

windows_chrome_driver = '/home/plonca/python_virtual_environments/selenium_jupyter_venv/bin/chromedriver.exe'
ubuntu_chrome_driver = '/home/plonca/python_virtual_environments/selenium_jupyter_venv/bin/chromedriver'

chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ubuntu_chrome_driver
                                , options=options
                                )
```

The problem occurs in the last line: if the `windows_chrome_driver` is set as `executable_path` everything is fine. If I set `ubuntu_chrome_driver` instead, I get an error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://bmlddehkgnjdalnfaecgflmmeknlbohi/_generated_background_page.html
from tab crashed
```

I wonder what the cause of the error might be. How to make `chrome_driver` work in the headless environment?

<sup>1</sup> The extension is needed so that I can authenticate via a pop-up window. The extension has been created according to instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114940/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-in-chrome-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java/56285073#56285073). Other options such as sending username and password in the URL or automating the click with AutoIt doesn't work.

<sup>2</sup> Please note that the Chrome seems to be the only option since using Firefox is a matter of an [unresolved issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662243/python-selenium-enable-logging-with-firefox-webdriver).

Comment: Did you figured this out?

Comment: I abandoned the solution based on scrapping for a more structured one.